# Failed to sync Gradle project / failed to find target with hash string

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-api, android-sdk-2.3

I currently have the "Failed to sync Gradle project / failed to find target with hash string" on Android Studio. I have Googled this problem for hours and all of the guides tell me to install the relevant SDKs, which I have done and redone multiple times. However, the problem persists (see screenshot). Is there anything I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to restart your Android Studio?

How is your gradle file?
Try to use `compileSdkVersion 19` instead of `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'`